# validate function with jquery not working for select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got working validate function for my input fields :

```
$.tools.validator.fn("#password", function(input, value) {
    return value!='Password' ? true : {     
        en: "Please complete this mandatory field"
    };
});

$("#form").validator({ 
    position: 'bottom left', 
    messageClass:'form-error',
    message: '<div><em/></div>' // em element is the arrow
});
```

My input field :

```
<input type="password" id="password" class="full" value="" name="j_password" required="required" placeholder="Password" />
```

And tried the same logic for select but it's not working :

```
$.tools.validator.fn("#environment", function(select, value) {
    return value!='Select Environment' ? true : {     
        en: "Please choose the environment"
    };
});
```

My select (not working):

```
<select id="environment" style="opacity: 0; "><option value="Select Environment">Select Environment</option><option value="1">Dev</option><option value="2">Test</option></select>
```

My select (not working as well ):

```
<select id="environment" style="opacity: 0; "><option>Select Environment</option><option>Dev</option><option>Test</option></select>
```

Can someone point out where I'm making mistake and how to fix it ?

**Update:**

I'm using http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/index.html

Comment: what error message are you getting in your console if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, well actually I didn't I found solution here :

https://gist.github.com/1810536

With following code :

```
 $.tools.validator.fn("#environment", function(input, value) {          
         return value!='Select Environment' ? true : {     
                en: "Please select which environment you want to logon"
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant but when I want to get the item selected from a dropdown I use `$('#dropDownID option:selected').val()`.

I would recommend displaying the value to see what you are actually getting, then try it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the **style="opacity: 0;"** and  Your code seems to work fine, see: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GDTwR/11/)

Answer (score 0):

If you try doing `$(select).val()` to get the value it should get the correct selected value from the select